# Unexpected token ' in JSON for stripe payment intents

Tags: node.js, json, stripe-payments

Hi I am working on create payment intent method in stripe  the language is node.js but I got this error

`unmatched close brace/bracket in URL position 13: currency:usd}'`

in my code when I execute this command:

```
curl -X POST localhost:4242/create-payment-intent -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"paymentMethodType":"card", "currency":"usd"}'
```

And this is my code

```
app.post('/create-payment-intent', async (req, res) => {
const {paymentMethodType, currency} = req.body;
  try {
    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
      amount: 1999,
      currency: currency,
      payment_method_types: [paymentMethodType],
    });
    res.json({ clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret });
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(400).json({ error: { message: e.message } });
  }
});
```

please any one can help.

Comment: can you post the error message of the catch block? btw everythings seems to be okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if You are using Window

```
curl -X POST localhost:4242/create-payment-intent -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{\"paymentMethodType\":\"card\", \"currency\":\"usd\"}"
```

Answer (score 0):

If your request has a JSON payload, you need to make sure your server is parsing that JSON. I tested the code below and it works on my end.

CURL command (no changes)

```
curl -X POST localhost:4242/create-payment-intent -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"paymentMethodType":"card", "currency":"usd"}'
```

Node.js server (added a middleware function to parse the JSON payload)

```
const json = express.json({ type: "application/json" });

app.post("/create-payment-intent", json, async (req, res) => {
  const { paymentMethodType, currency } = req.body;
  try {
    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
      amount: 1999,
      currency: currency,
      payment_method_types: [paymentMethodType],
    });
    res.json({ clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret });
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(400).json({ error: { message: e.message } });
  }
});
```

Comment: HI thanks for your replay but when i execute the code the show me :                                          <pre>SyntaxError: Unexpected token p in JSON at position 1<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at JSON.parse (&lt;anonymous&gt;)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at parse (C:\ok\htdocs\tutorial1\server\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:89:19)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at C:\ok\htdocs\tutorial1\server\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:121:18<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at invokeCallback (C:\ok\htdocs\tutorial1\server\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at done (C:\ok\htdocs\tutorial1\server\node

Comment: when i execute this command its work: curl -X POST localhost:4242/create-payment-intent -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{}' and give the answer but when  i pass the parameters they give me error

Answer (score -1):

You forget to add `'` at the end of your command

```sh
curl -X POST localhost:4242/create-payment-intent -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"paymentMethodType":"card", "currency":"usd"}'
```

Comment: but again show me the same error